# Rewriting a double integral with indicator function

Tags: probability, integration, numerical-methods

I have to evaluate the following double integral for nonnegative constants $a, b$ and $c$.

$$\frac{1}{ab}\int_0^a dx\int_0^b dy\ \  \mathbb{1}_{x+y \geq c}$$

where $\mathbb{1}$ refers to the indicator function and equals $1$ if the condition in the subscript is true and $0$ otherwise.

How can I rewrite this to evaluate this numerically on a computer? The goal would be to get rid of the indicator function from the problem description. For a single integral, a solution is done here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/479727/integrating-indicator-function but I am having trouble extending the idea to double integrals.

Comment: Are you familiar with Fubini's or Tonelli's theorems?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur I know Fubini's theorem but I do know how to deal with functions in the limits of the integrals. For instance, we would have things like $\max(c-x, 0)$ as one of the limits of the $dy$ integral...

Comment: I essentially meant about connecting a nested integral to a $2$-dimensional integral. This follows from Fubini.

Comment: If you known probability, then another way to think about it is $$P(X+Y\geq c)= E[P(X+Y\geq c\mid X)]$$, where $(X,Y)\sim \mathcal U[0,a]\otimes \mathcal U[0,b]$

Comment: @Andrew yes, but how can one compute the quantity on the right? I like the geometric perspective of the accepted answer but it is difficult to extend that approach to $n$ random variables instead of $2$.

Comment: $$P(X+Y\geq c \mid X) = \varphi(X),\quad \varphi(x) = P(Y \geq c-x)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the order of integration using Fubini's theorem, you can rewrite

$$ \frac{1}{ab}\int_0^a dx\int_0^b dy\ \  \mathbb{1}_{\{x+y \geq c\}}= \frac{1}{ab} \int_{[0,a]\times[0,b]} \mathbb{1}_{\{x+y \geq c\}}dxdy \;. $$

The right hand side is simply the area of $[0,a]\times[0,b]$ intersected with $\{(x,y):x+y\geq c \}$ divided by the area of $[0,a]\times[0,b]$. When $c\leq 0$ this is simply $1$. When $c\geq b+a$ this is $0$.

The rest of the cases can be computed by considering how the line $y=-x+c$ intersects the rectangle $[0,a]\times[0,b]$ and understanding the area in the rectangle to the right of this line.

Comment: Thanks, and for higher dimensions, is there a way to generalize this? The shape whose volume one must find gets quite complex

Comment: @user1936752 Depends on what you mean. But, if you are talking about a direct analogue to this question, I would say yes. The answer would then usually be a volume of some $d$-dimensional body.

Comment: Small note: some of the inequalities here are backwards!

Comment: @Sambo I hope this is correct now. Thanks for pointing it out.